# Display a .mp4 video on a web site in compatibility with HTML 4.01 strict

Tags: html, video, mp4, html4

The solution has to be accepted with neither errors nor warnings by [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check), therefore the "video" tag known from HTML5 is obviously incorrect. Movie is placed in file at the same directory as web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the given conditions, the only way is to embed the video with an [`object` elemen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)t:

```
<object data=vodka.mp4 width=300 height=150>
  See the <a href=vodka.mp4>video of our hamster</a>.
</object>
```

Browser support is limited, and even on supporting browsers, the user may be prompted for a permission to run a plug-in. So the idea of disallowing `video` is odd, but I guess this is a school project, where such misguided requirements are imposed on formal and not-well-informed basis.

Comment: how would i play or preferably autoplay the video instead of linking to it?